# Django's best way to load data into postresql database

Tags: django, postgresql

I’m working in a project that consists in converting a local postgresql database (that uses sqlalchemy as the ORM) into a web application, in which I upload excel sheets, read them, do some small cleaning and then upload selected data into a postgresql database using Django’s ORM. The idea is to have the data in a server instead of in every user’s machine. 
Everything is ok but data loading is taking too long since, I think, I am using panda’s dataframes to easily structure, read and save the data. In the local version of the library, I used lists and was way faster.

I don’t if it’s related to Sqlalchemy, Django, lists or dataframes. Any suggestions on how to read spreadsheets data and upload it into a postgresql database using Django?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use Django's dumpdata/loaddata feature

1. Dumpdata
   Outputs to standard output all data in the database associated with the named application(s).

If no application name is provided, all installed applications will be dumped.

2. Loaddata
   Searches for and loads the contents of the named fixture into the database.

For for info you can refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata)